# Careers 2.0 promotion

Tags: discussion, jobs, site-promotion

### TL;DR

Careers relies on location. For example France has no (little) representation on the site. 
This question is divided in X parts :

1. How can C2.0 be promoted where it is not used.
2. Given the pay/invite system, how can we ensures the spreading of usage across countries.
3. How should we consider other Jobs sites like linkedIn

---

### Detailed post

#### Promotion

I've been trying Careers today. I think expanding the stackexchange experience is really a plus for people who need to get a job or looking to hire.

But... I've just search jobs around "Paris" (France) within 500 miles and got nearly ... 10 results ... in England and Germany.
So I guess that Careers is not known of recruiters in France. So I was wondering how can the site be promoted to make it grow within an area? (I guess this is not specific to France)

Do we know how many [French] are on Careers? Is there promotional material like banners and other that can be used on other social networks? Are you looking for partnerships for promotion? How do you promote it elsewhere?

#### Spreading

I thought of something else.

The site needs people.

- Employers
- Candidates

Employers pay a subscription, candidates can make a profile on invite only.
To make employer pay for the service, you need candidates. Is there a significant ratin of invitation dispersion across countries? Or else it will just stay localised.

I can understand that stackoverflow or other SE sites grow up naturally, but they are not bound to countries like people are. I mean it's easy for anyone speaking English to participate in SO. And even better : IT mostly requires English in a day to day basis.

Then what about Careers 2.0?

#### Concurrence

Other jobs sites: LinkedIn, viadeo and others. Are they to be fear? 
Surely the audience is not the same. But they gather a lot of people. Should we care to push the quality of programmers on Careers 2.0 against those sites? Like : "The reference in IT recruitment" ?

Do we have other particularities?

Comment: It's probably going to have to grow. StackOverflow grew pretty big without any promotion - I assume the plan for careers is similar

Comment: I got your point. But stackoverflow is a Q&A site. Now we are talking about people themselves. So it needs people ready to be recruited to attract manager (the employer section is on subscription if I understand well)

Comment: There are some [usage stats](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-overflow-around-the-world) - given the visitor numbers aren't a million miles from Germany/UK, there's either a lack of awareness or some legal/cultural aversion to the approach. Careers is an oddball - contrary to many things SO does, the "domain experts" (3rd parties who source code monkeys) are excluded. I expect progress to be [slow](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/overnight-success-it-takes-years.html).

Answer (score 1):

The last time I looked, in Manchester (UK) there were so few people with CVs on Careers 2.0 that there was no point in getting my employer to look at using it.   Manchester is the 3rd largest city in the UK and has a reasonable programming job market.

So I think Careers needs to be close to free for employers until there is a given number of an active candidate within a 30 minutes commute of the employer’s location.

At present I don’t think it is likely to be worth the time of a candidate posting a CV on Careers, as most jobs are on JobServe anyway.  Hopefully this “chicken and egg” problem will get sorted out somehow.